# NodeJS FTP not throwing error when trying to delete non-existent file

Tags: node.js, ftp, node-modules, ftp-client, nodejs-server

I am working with ftp-npm and I am currently facing a weird bug...

I have a method called refreshStore that contains this part of code :

```
c.delete('/pathToMyFileOnFTPServer', function(err) {
            console.log('117');
            if (err) throw err;
          });
```

This is not throwing error and even not logging the '117' string even though my file does not exist on the server... Why is this like this ?

Thanks all!